# How should I render the tpl of module at theme

Tags: 7, theming

I create a module and mymodule.module file like this:

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['mymodule/list']=array(
        'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback'=>'mymodule_list_view',
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_list_view(){
    theme('list_view');
}

function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
        'list_view'=>array(
            'template'=>'mymodule_list',
            'type'=>'theme_engins',
        ),
    );
}
```

then I create templates file: mymodule_list.tpl.php

And I create a theme and create templates file: page--mymodule.tpl.php. Now when I access /mymodule/list, it will use page--mymodule.tpl.php to render the page.

My question is: how should I write page--mymodule.tpl.php to display the content in mymodule_list.tpl.php?

Comment: plz elaborate this

Comment: page--mymodule.tpl.php should just be a copy of page.tpl.php

Comment: I found that the content of mymodule_list.tpl.php was saved at the variable `$page['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup']`, so I think I should process this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a customized page template file because you are using a template file for your theme. What you need to do is to fix your code, which should be as the following one.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/list'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_list_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_list_view() {
  return theme('list_view');
}

function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'list_view' => array(
      'template' => 'list-view',
    ),
  );
}
```

Notice that:

- For the menu callback, you should define the access callback, and the access arguments, or the menu will not be visible to the users (except the user #1). By default, Drupal uses `user_access()` as access callback; in this case, you need to provide the permission string as access arguments.
- The template filename must be equal to the theme name; the only acceptable difference is the underscores replaced by hyphens.
- Your page callback needs to return its output, or print it. In the first case, the rendered page will contain all the output returned from Drupal, such as blocks; in the second case, the rendered page will just contain what your page callback prints.